# CKEditor render angular custom directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ckeditor

I have an HTML editor using CKEditor on my page. Now we decided create some custom directives using AngularJS but CKEditor replaces the "unknown" tags by other HTML Tags.

example:

```
 <custom-table
      dataset="Person"
      headers = "['Name', 'Email']"
      fields = "['name', 'email']">
 </custom-table>
```

is replaced by:

```
<p>&nbsp</p>
```

I don't want to render that custom tag. I just want to make CKEditor allows "unknown" tags without change it. Is that possible?

Comment: try `extraAllowedContent`? http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.config-cfg-extraAllowedContent

Comment: @BrianGlaz It works. Please add it as an answer so I can give you the credits!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you refer to the documentation for CK Editor here: http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.config-cfg-extraAllowedContent

It mentions a `extraContentAllowed` option, letting you specify which HTML elements are valid.